# How to insert range of datas from asp.net textboxes into SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have two textboxes `startno` and `endno` and a column `Number` in SQL Server. I want to insert values between `startno` and `endno`. Say if I enter 1 in `startno` textbox and 10 in `endno` textbox, then values (1, 2, ..., 10) should be inserted in the SQL Server column `Number`.

In C# we use `for(i = 1; i <= 10; i++)`... but how to do it in T-SQL, or is there `for` statement in stored procedures?

Comment: There are more than one solution. `Recursive Cte`, `WHILE`, `CROSS JOIN`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you need to use the C# loop and execute the statement multiple times, look into using a SQL bulk copy method if the number of columns can get very large or lastly you can build the values section as a comma delimited string and pass that in to the stored procedure and execute it then as dynamic SQL.